# How do I provide heating to a room without existing plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, heating

I have a house in the Republic of Ireland which has 2 rooms without heating. One is a Kitchen and the other is planned to be a 'breakfast' room.

[image: Terrible sketch of section of house]

(all rooms are approx 5m x 3m)

As can be (hopefully) deciphered from the sketch, there is a radiator on the other side of the concrete floored hallway, a fireplace in the breakfast room, and the main house boiler on an adjoining wall.

The Kitchen floors are tiled and I would prefer not to remove/damage them so am trying to figure out how best to heat the rooms.

(Please do ask in comments if you need more/better detail on anything. I'm trying to keep the question concise)

Answer (score 1):

Just go up. The 2 ceilings get a moderate slit for a lot of drilling & short sections of piping with a wall & ceiling corner chunk-out to drop down for the new rads.

And, if the current piping is old then tie in the existing rad to avoid any near-future failures. That piping would be parallel to the joists & you'd just need a chunk-out at the bearing wall & above the existing rad.

Tedious, but gets it done & the ceilings are the easiest to repair compared to everything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a fast and simple solution to heat the rooms I would suggest *electric baseboards* as a heating source. They install along most any approved wall and are available in different voltage. All that is needed is a electric source to tap into.

Comment: Plus: simple and cheap installation, easy to "zone" onits own thermostat. Minus: higher ongoing cost per therm of heating, until/unless an especially cheap source of electricity is available (eg, new-generation nuclear). Best suited to spaces which are only occasionally heated to occupancy temperatures, such as guest rooms.

Answer (score 1):

Use plug-in oscillating ceramic element space heaters with electronic thermostat control, you just leave them on with the temperature set. Quiet, efficient, effective, and not hot to the touch. No invasive plumbing or wiring. We use one in the guest house main room (400 sq/ft) and it's nice and toasty all winter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can remove the skirting from the wall to the right of the hallway, chase pipes into the wall from existing radiator up to intersection with breakfast-room and kitchen and have radiators on the other side of the walls left and right of that intersection.

You can buy skirting boards / capping designed to cover pipes fixed to the wall.